# Deleting more than one song at one time on my iPhone?

Tags: music, music.app

I need help finding a way to delete more than one song at a time on my iPhone. Can someone tell me if that is possible?

I have tried deleting songs on my iTunes and then syncing them but it does not work and it takes way too much time.

Comment: Which iOS version?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by deleting albums, artists or compilations from the respective views. Swipe right on the item to get the `Delete` button and tap it to delete an entire album, an entire artist's works or an entire compilation. This still works only one (album or artist or compilation) at a time. There is no way to select multiple albums or artists or compilations for deletion.

Comment: I could not delete albums/artists, swipe right and nothing happens, on 5s/ios7

Answer (score 0):

you cant delete albums or artists on the i phone. you just have to delete songs 1 by 1